# Visual Studio 2017 Debugger Won't Refresh Browser Anymore

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, localhost, visual-studio-2017

I've used VS for 10 years and have never had this problem until yesterday. I can no longer see changes to my website when I'm debugging using localhost. 
For example...I make a change to a .aspx page while I'm debugging and refresh the page in my browser (ctrl+F5), but the change does not appear.  Here's what I've tried so far:

> Chrome and Firefox
>
> Exiting IISExpress
>
> Stopping debugger and restarting
>
> Creating a new .aspx page
>
> Closing my solution
>
> Creating a brand new solution
>
> Trying other solutions
>
> Closing VS
>
> Restarting my machine (Windows 7)
>
> Enabling/Disabling BrowserLink
>
> Deleting my Solution (.sln) file
>
> Running VS as administrator
>
> Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>.NET CORE (unchecked "Don't call MSBuild if a project appears to be upt to date")
>
> Added  Response.Write("Test"); to Page Load of code behind.  Did not show up until I restarted VS.  After adding a second line and setting a breakpoint on it, VS does not recognize the breakpoint and line 2 does not show up in browser.

Important Notes:

> .html pages work fine.
>
> The solution builds successfully.
>
> The only change to my system was a windows update the day before that
>   installed .NET Core SDK - 2.0.3(x64) and updates to Adobe Flash Player
>   27.

Comment: Getting any errors/info in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary.  I also tried changing the option under Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run select "Always build" under "On Run, when projects are out of date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of trying, finally found a solution.  Had to go into the control panel => Programs and Features => right click on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 => Change => on the Change Screen look for the "More" drop down and pick "Repair".  Took a long time and required a restart but it appears to have solved the issue.

Comment: since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer, thanks for sharing your solution here. Have a nice day:)